# Linq challenge: converting this piece of code from method chain to standard Linq

Tags: c#, linq, method-chaining

The challenge is about converting from method chain to standard linq a piece of code full of group by.

### The context

To fully understand the topic here you can read the original question (with class definitions, sample data and so on): [Linq: rebuild hierarchical data from the flattened list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52745192/linq-rebuild-hierarchical-data-from-the-flattened-list)

Thanks to @Akash Kava, I've found the solution to my problem.

### Chain method formulation

```
var macroTabs = flattenedList
        .GroupBy(x => x.IDMacroTab)
        .Select((x) => new MacroTab
        {
            IDMacroTab = x.Key,
            Tabs = x.GroupBy(t => t.IDTab)
                    .Select(tx => new Tab {
                        IDTab = tx.Key,
                        Slots = tx.Select(s => new Slot {
                           IDSlot = s.IDSlot
                     }).ToList()
            }).ToList()
        }).ToList();
```

But, for sake of knowledge, I've tried to convert the method chain to the standard Linq formulation but something is wrong.

What happens is similar to this..

### My attempt to convert it to Linq standard syntax

```
var antiflatten = flattenedList
    .GroupBy(x => x.IDMacroTab)
    .Select(grouping => new MacroTab
    {
        IDMacroTab = grouping.Key,
        Tabs = (from t in grouping
                group grouping by t.IDTab
                into group_tx
                select new Tab
                {
                    IDTab = group_tx.Key,
                    Slots = (from s in group_tx
                    from s1 in s    
                    select new Slot
                    {
                        IDSlot = s1.IDSlot
                    }).ToList()
                }).ToList()
    });
```

### The result in LinqPad

[image]

### The classes and the sample data on NetFiddle:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/8mF1qI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This challenge helped me to understand what exactly returns a Linq Group By (and how prolix is the Linq syntax with Group By).

As `LinqPad` clearly shows a *Group By* returns a `List` of `Groups`. `Group` is a very simple class which has **just one property**: a **Key**

[image]

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18359745/196210) states, from definition of IGrouping (`IGrouping<out TKey, out TElement> : IEnumerable<TElement>, IEnumerable`) the **only** way to access to the content of the subgroups is to iterate through elements (a foreach, another group by, a select, ecc).

Here is shown the Linq syntax formulation of the method chain.

[image]

[And here is the source code on Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/x5GhIa)

But let's go on trying to see another solution:

What we usually do in **SQL** when we do a **Group By** is to list all the columns **but** the one which have been grouped. *With Linq is different.. it still returns ALL the columns.*

In this example we started with a dataset with 3 'columns' {IDMacroTab, IDTab, IDSlot}. We grouped for the first column, but Linq would return the whole dataset, unless we explicitly tell him..

[image]